# Able to run in Eclipse, but Force close On mobile

Tags: android, forceclose

my ordering application after login page will go to Scanner, List , and Order.
After i click Order is go to the catalog, it is able to run on eclipse virtual device, but not able to work on mobile. other page is ok

this is the CatalogActivity.java

```
package com.example.barcode;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CatalogActivity extends Activity {

 private List<Product> mProductList;
 Button button;


 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.catalog);

  // Obtain a reference to the product catalog
  mProductList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCatalog(getResources());

  // Create the list
  ListView listViewCatalog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCatalog);
  listViewCatalog.setAdapter(new ProductAdapter(mProductList, getLayoutInflater(), false));

 listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
   Intent productDetailsIntent = new         Intent(getBaseContext(),ProductDetailsActivity.class);
   productDetailsIntent.putExtra(ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX, position);
  startActivity(productDetailsIntent);
}
});

Button viewShoppingCart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonViewCart);
viewShoppingCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent viewShoppingCartIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ShoppingCartActivity.class);
  startActivity(viewShoppingCartIntent);
 }
});

}
```

}

and here is the catlog from phone

04-09 01:45:45.174 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

```
04-09 01:45:45.174 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:45:48.484 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:45:48.484 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:45:56.939 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:45:56.939 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:45:57.424 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:45:57.424 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:45:57.429 E/System  (30213): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer

04-09 01:45:57.429 E/System  (30213): java.io.IOException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)

04-09 01:45:57.429 E/System  (30213):   at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:41)

04-09 01:45:57.429 E/System  (30213):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.close(FileOutputStream.java:139)

04-09 01:45:57.429 E/System  (30213):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.finalize(FileOutputStream.java:153)

04-09 01:45:57.429 E/System  (30213):   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:186)

04-09 01:45:57.429 E/System  (30213):   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)

04-09 01:45:57.429 E/System  (30213):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

04-09 01:45:57.429 E/System  (30213): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)

04-09 01:45:57.429 E/System  (30213):   at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)

04-09 01:45:57.429 E/System  (30213):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)

04-09 01:45:57.429 E/System  (30213):   at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:38)

04-09 01:45:57.429 E/System  (30213):   ... 5 more

04-09 01:45:57.434 E/System  (30213): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer

04-09 01:45:57.434 E/System  (30213): java.io.IOException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)

04-09 01:45:57.434 E/System  (30213):   at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:41)

04-09 01:45:57.434 E/System  (30213):   at java.io.FileInputStream.close(FileInputStream.java:121)
04-09 01:45:57.434 E/System  (30213):   at java.io.FileInputStream.finalize(FileInputStream.java:142)

04-09 01:45:57.434 E/System  (30213):   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:186)

04-09 01:45:57.434 E/System  (30213):   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)

04-09 01:45:57.434 E/System  (30213):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

04-09 01:45:57.434 E/System  (30213): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)

04-09 01:45:57.434 E/System  (30213):   at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)

04-09 01:45:57.434 E/System  (30213):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)

04-09 01:45:57.434 E/System  (30213):   at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:38)

04-09 01:45:57.434 E/System  (30213):   ... 5 more

04-09 01:45:58.214 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:45:58.214 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:46:00.394 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:46:00.394 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:46:30.454 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:46:30.454 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:46:30.879 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:46:30.879 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:47:01.334 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:47:01.334 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:47:02.439 E/Dynamiclayout(30213): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0

04-09 01:47:02.664 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:47:02.664 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:47:22.089 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:47:22.089 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:47:23.169 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

04-09 01:47:23.169 E/SpannableStringBuilder(30213): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Comment: what line in your code throws the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You must find the string that has zero lenght. Is that the full log generated when the error occurs?
IO exceptions happen when you read a file however in the posted code there are no file operations.
Also this part of your code seems to have no mistakes.

Comment: sry i cant catch what u mean, can u explain for me?